# How do I write a query with LIKE against a column with Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, sql-like

I have a PSQL table with a text column and a query

```
select * from table where :number: like column||'%';
```

where `:number:` is a parameter.

How can I write that query in Spring Data JPA? The LIKE stuff of Spring Data seems to take only a text parameter, not a column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using [JPA Criteria Queries](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries) or [Specifications](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/). Both use [Path#get(String attributeName)](https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/criteria/Path/get_String) to create a path corresponding to the referenced column name. I assume you have an entity named `Table`.

Example with Criteria Queries:

```
public List<Table> getCoulmnLikeNumber(String columnName, String number) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Table> critQuery = builder.createQuery(Table.class);
    Root<Table> root = critQuery.from(Table.class);

    Expression<String> pattern = builder.concat(root.<String>get(columnName), "%");
    critQuery.select(root)
             .where(builder.like(builder.literal(number), pattern));

    return getEntityManager()
            .createQuery(critQuery)
            .getResultList();
}
```

A factory method for your specification could look similar to this:

```
public static Specification<Table> columnNameLikeNumber(String columnName, String number) {
    return new Specification<Table>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Entity> root,
                                     CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
            Expression<String> pattern = builder.concat(root.<String>get(columnName), "%");
            return builder.like(builder.literal(number), pattern);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this specification produces a query with the wrong order: `column||'%' like 'number'` - I need `'number' like column||'%'`.

Comment: If you wrap `number` with `CriteriaBuilder#literal()` you can swap the order. See my edited answer.